Can't send emails on gmail using Thunderbird
Suddenly I can't send emails on gmail using Thunderbird though web method works OK. I have TLS/SSL with OAuth2 & port 465. When I try resetting the 'password' it refuses to accept it though it's the same as My Google account's one: it just displays the window for it again. I'm using Ubuntu 22.04 with Thunderbird 115.13.0.
PS TB can save drafts and mark emails as read.

This question is similar to: New install 24.04: Thunderbird cannot send emails. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.
